# Show that the space $ℓ^0=\{\{a_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathbb C\mid a_j=0\text{ for } j>>1\}$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Show that the space $$\ell^0=\{\{a_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}\subset \mathbb C\mid a_j=0 \text{ for } j\gg1\}$$ with inner product $$(a,b) \in ℓ^0\timesℓ^0 \mapsto \langle a,b\rangle =\sum_{j=1}^\infty {a_j}{b_j}$$ (where $a=\{a_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ and $b=\{b_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ )
is not complete.

I found this problem on the Internet but I am wondering if it's clear and if it has sufficient data to prove it. I want your help if anyone can give me a proof.

Comment: I cleaned up some of the formatting, but it isn't clear what $C$ is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: i think it's the set of complex numbers

Comment: @paris I gave an answer... providing that your $\ell^0$ space is the space of complex sequences that are eventually vanishing. Please confirm that it is the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If I understood you well, your $\ell^0$ is the space of complex sequences that are eventually vanishing.*

If that is right, consider the sequence $(c_n) \in (\ell^0)^{\mathbb N}$ defined by $c_n(k) = \frac{1}{k}$ for $1 \le k \le n$ and $c_n(k) = 0$ for $k > n$.

$(c_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence as for $n < m$ $$\Vert c_n - c_m \Vert^ 2=\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}$$ tends to $0$ for $n < m$ large enough as the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges.

However, if $(c_n)$ was converging in $\ell^0$, that would be to the sequence $(\frac{1}{k})_{k \ge 1}$ which doesn't belong to $\ell^0$ as it is not eventually vanishing.

Comment: Fine, except you need to clean up the notation! You have a sequence of elements of $\ell^0$, each of which is a sequence; problem is you're using the same notation for that sequence of elements and for the coordinates of one of the sequences. Same problem arises all the time with sequence spaces. Maybe something like $(c^n)\subset \ell^0$, where $c^n=(c^n_j)=(c^n_1,c^n_2,\dots)$.

Comment: @David Good comment. I modified the answer which is hopefully more consistent for the notations now!